# how to read the data from google spreadsheet using php

Tags: google-sheets

I'm getting confusion to start the code, could you please guide me to complete.

How to read the data from Google spreadsheet and store the data into variable using php

I have spreadsheet in Google Drive, I have data like:

```
s.no name mobilenumber
1    raghu   888888888
2    ram     777777777
```

I want to get the mobile number according to name condition:

`if(name==ram){
    mobile="";// have to store the particular number here
    }`

From spreadsheet using PHP

Comment: Add more information to your post. Such as what data needs to be read, how large the file is, where you want to store it etc.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience just now i have edited the code. Please help me